# Mysql Counting different column with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have a table where each row represent a correction with an id, date and a causes

```
id | date                | causes
___________________________________

1  | 2018-01-29 08:49:19 | crash
2  | 2018-08-08 10:03:37 | timeout
3  | 2018-06-26 07:48:12 | other
```

I use this sql request to get the number of correction by month

```
SELECT YEAR(date) Year, MONTH(date) Month, count(*) Total FROM correction group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

It gives me a result like this

```
Year | Month | Total
____________________

2018 |   1   | 42
2018 |   2   | 69
2018 |   3   | 50
```

Is it possible to modify the request to also get the number of result for each causes and have a result like :

```
 Year | Month | Total | crash | timeout | other
 ____________________________________________

 2018 |   1   | 42   | 10     | 12      | 20
 2018 |   2   | 69   | 9      | 50      | 10
 2018 |   3   | 50   | 10     | 20      | 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *conditional* aggregation :

```
SELECT YEAR(date) Year, MONTH(date) Month, COUNT(*) Total,
       SUM(causes = 'crash') crash,
       SUM(causes = 'timeout') timeout,
       SUM(causes = 'other') other
FROM correction c 
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date);
```